# How to pass driver instance across multiple sub-tabs in a page using Selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, salesforce

I am new to Salesforce. I am trying to do automation in a Salesforce page (Lightning Experience). The page i am working now has the following design,

1. Search Box at the top of the page
2. Search Results as sub-tabs in the same page

How do i pass the driver instance to the current displayed sub-tab of the same page ?

Currenly, when i am trying to access the page elements of the newly opened sub-tab, it throws exception as the driver is still held with the first opened tab and fetching its elements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to return SearchResultTab class object from Search Class which initializes the elements of subtabs. Try below code. Please read code over which comment is written in Search class.

```
public class Search {

    private WebDriver driver;       
    @FindBy(css=".LM6RPg")
    private WebElement searchTextBox;

    @FindBy(css = ".vh79eN")
    private WebElement searchButton;

    public Search(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    // A method which initializes tab page on submitting search page

    public SearchResults searchInStore(String query) {
        searchTextBox.sendKeys(query + Keys.SPACE);
        searchButton.click();
        return new SearchTab(driver, query);
    }
}

public class SearchTab {

    @FindBy(css="._1ZODb3")
    public WebElement tabElement1;

    @FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using = "//div[@class='_3wU53n']")
    public List<WebElement> tabElement2;



    public SearchResults(WebDriver driver, String query) {
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        wait = new WebDriverWait(this.driver,2000);
    }

}

public class SearchTabTest{


   @Test
    public void testProductSearch() {

                Search search = new Search(Browser.driver);
                SearchResults searchResults = search.Search().searchInStore("iphone 5s");
                searchResults.tabElement1.getText();
                searchResults.tabElement2.getText();
    }   

}

public class Browser {

    private static WebDriver driver;

    public static WebDriver driver() {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/browserdrivers/chromedriver.exe");
        DesiredCapabilities caps = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        caps.setCapability(ChromeOptions.CAPABILITY, options);
        driver = new ChromeDriver(caps);
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
        return driver;
    }

    public static void open(String url) {
        driver.get(url);
    }

    public static void close() {
        driver.quit();
    }
}
```

Comment: i have added this line in my script file SearchResults searchResults = agentcare.searchInStore("XXXX"); and had search method public SearchResults searchInStore (String query) {
driver.findElement(By.xpath(searchsalesforce)).sendKeys(query);        
driver.findElement(By.xpath(searchsalesforce)).sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);
return new SearchResults(driver, query);  } and had my tab objects defined in SearchResults as @FindBy(xpath="//div[contains(@title,'XXXX')]/a")
public WebElement LoginUser; public SearchResults (WebDriver driver, String query) {//} .  But could not fetch LoginUser in script

Comment: can you please clarify why i am not able to fetch the LoginUser element in my script after this step. ?

Comment: You have to logically arrange chain of methods from one page class to another so to access login elements u should have methods like
loginPage.homePage.SearchPage.SearchPageTabResults();
These are links for full example
Page -https://github.com/amitjaincoer191/seleniumTraining/tree/master/src/main/java/com/globallogic/page
Tests -https://github.com/amitjaincoer191/seleniumTraining/blob/master/src/test/java/com/globallogic/test/SearchTest.java

Comment: Amit, the search text will open a page where i will login to that account. so i trust they are arranged logically.

Comment: It means after Entering text in searchBox and submit button click it should return LoginPage class object which will return back the obj of SearchResultTab class after Login.

Comment: i search for "User Account Login Page" it will show me all the search related to that User Account Login Page (1st tab). From this page i will click the hyperlink to open that account. This opens up the main page for that user account(2nd tab). This has LOGIN button to login to that account. clicking on it, this account is opened in 3rd tab and it goes on that way. I am now trying to move my driver instance from search to 1st tab and find this hyperlink element. I followed the way you suggested still this hyperlink element i am not able to fetch as the driver instance is not moved to this page